# Why is Ŭ the only hat-letter [Ĉ, Ĝ, Ĥ, Ĵ, Ŝ, Ŭ] that doesn't use a circumflex?

Tags: history, typography

All of the Esperanto diacritic characters use a circumflex except for Ŭ. Is there a reason that the letter ended up this way. Why isn't it Û instead, to go better with the other diacritic characters?

Comment: I think it would look too much like an O, but I am not sure of the official reason.

Comment: I always thought it was because U is a vowel, and the other letters are consonants. The nature of the pronunciation modification is different.

Answer (score 8):

As opposed to the *ĉapelo*, the *luneto* has an explicit historic inspiration. [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%AC#cite_ref-2) that

> It is thought that ŭ was created by analogy with the Belarusian letter ў (Cyrillic u with breve), which was proposed by P.A. Bessonov in 1870.

Virtually the same is stated with more certainty in the corresponding [Vikipedio entry](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%AC):

> Ŭ estas invento de Zamenhof, modifo de U pere de Cirila signeto, la hoketo (aŭ "luneto" aŭ "duonarko").

I doubt that more concrete sources have survived.

Why reuse (the accent of) a Cyrillic letter for ŭ and not reuse the existing Latin symbols č, š for ĉ, ŝ eludes me. ([Some say](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9C) the latter is to maintain neutrality, but that would seem to clash with the former.) But as per why not use the same artificially introduced accent for both modifications, I think the quick answer is that the purpose is different: the *luneto* converts the vowel into a semivowel (thus, simply put, affects *length*), while the *ĉapelo* changes the *sound*. One could in principle extend the effect of the former to other vowels to represent diphtongs that are not present in Esperanto using its orthography. (With Ŭ alone ŭo and oŭ are examples of this.)

**Edit:** U is the only one for which it makes sense: for I we have J, and [other common cardinal vowels used for forming semivowels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivowel) do not exist in Esperanto.

Comment: On a side note, I completely agree with you. In my first days I even accidentally tagged a "typo" in Duolingo because I thought they used ŭ by mistake, until that point I was just convinced that what I saw was a û.

Comment: Also in German handwriting in Zamenhof's time was used the ŭ to indicate the diphtong like in *Ein Haŭs* (a house). I think more likely Zamenhof used the german ŭ than the cyrillic ў as an example.

Comment: I think the *ŭ* in German handwriting was used for any *u*, not just those in diphthongs, to differentiate it from other similar-looking cursive letters. .

Answer (score 6):

Mi opinias la supozon pri Belorusa origino de nia "ŭ" ne tre konvinka. Tiu Cirila litero (ў) estis proponita en 1870 kaj malmulte uzata antaŭ la 20-a jarcento. Eble Zamenhof, kies ĉefaj lingvoj estis la Rusa kaj la Jida, ja konis ĝin kaj ĝi povis havi etan signifon en la kreado de la Esperanta alfabeto. Mi tamen kredas, ke la ĉefaj motivoj por le elekto de nia u-hoketo estis aliaj.

Se ni rigardas la Cirilan alfabeton, pli forta modelo por la formo de la supersigno estas la Rusa literparo "ий". Ĝi respondas al niaj literoj "ij", sed estas precipe analoga kun la Esperanta "uŭ" en tio, ke la litero й estas uzata post vokalo por formi diftongojn. Ekzemple, niaj diftongoj "aj oj", transskribitaj en la Rusan estas "ай ой", kaj la supersigno de "й" estas tre simila al tiu de nia "ŭ". La Rusa supersigno havas similan *funkcion* kiel nia ronda hoketo.

Tamen eĉ pli mi vidas en la supersigno de "ŭ" influon de la tute simila mallongo-signo uzata en vortaroj de Latino por neprigi mallongan prononcon de vokalo (en la Angla oni nomas la signon *breve*). Ankaŭ en poezio, por indiki manieron de skandado, oni povis tiel montri mallongecon, dum longecon montris superlitera streketo: ū). Latina vortaro povis tiel apartigi, ekzemple, la vortojn "ŭter" kaj "ūter". Zamenhof estis scianto de la klasikaj Eŭropaj lingvoj kaj certe konis tiun filologian metodon marki longan prononcon, kaj la litero "ŭ" tiel estis por li natura elekto. Nia "ŭ" ja estas fakte mallonga "u", ĉiam senakcenta.

Mi samopinias kun Paŭl Peeraerts, ke eĉ la Germana manskriba "u" estas pli probabla origino ol la Cirila litero.

La ĉapeloj de "ĉĝĥĵŝ" tiam (1887) ne aperis sur konsonantoj en iu latinlitera nacia lingvo. Simile, mankis modelo por la vokalo "ŭ"; tian literon oni trovis nur en filologiaj vortlistoj de klasikistoj. Eble Zamenhof elektis la literojn ĝuste pro tio, ke lia lingvo aspektu pli neŭtrala, pri memstara, ne tro simila al iu aŭ alia lingvo. Por li verŝajne estis nenia problemo presigi la unuan libron kun la ĝustaj literoj. Nur la postaj generacioj komencis fervore fabriki al si artefaritajn problemojn pri la afero.

Demandoj de la tipo "kial io en Esperanto estas ĝuste tia" estas ĉiam malfacile respondeblaj kaj, se oni respondas, la respondo havas karakteron iom spekulativan.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question.  I tend to see the ŭ as a weak vowel as opposed to a strong vowel, which would create a new syllable and changing the stress of the word. "Laŭ" is pronounced as a one syllable word whereas "Lau" should be pronounced as a two syllable word.  Using the ĉapelo is mainly for providing a varied pronunciation of a consonant.

I see the logic in it, though, I'm only inferring and have no concrete sources to back up my reasoning other than a personal inference that makes a great deal of sense to me.